# Can't execute application in crontab

Tags: cron

I have created an application using .Net Core that communicates with a server. I published that application for CentOS x64, and I am currently failing to execute it as a task in crontab.

This is what I did:

1) I gave it full permissions with the command:

```
chmod 777 ApplicationName
```

Note: After this step, if I go to its folder and do `./ApplicationName` it works fine and logs data to a file in the client and sends information to the server.

2) I created a task using the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

With the line:

```
* * * * * root cd "/ApplicationPath" && ./ApplicationName
```

Note: If I run `cd "/ApplicationPath" && ./ApplicationName` it works fine and logs data in a file in the client and sends information to my server.

3) Then, I restarted cron by doing:

```
service crond stop
service crond start
```

4) Waited some minutes and didn't do anything. No log file on client or data sent to server...

I checked cron logs at `/var/log/cron` and I find the following line repeated for each minute:

```
[date] [hostname] CROND[28554]: (root) CMD (root cd "/ApplicationPath" && ./ApplicationName)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your first issue is that your crontab format is incorrect (extraneous user field): see [cron not executing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236536/cron-not-executing). There may be other issues such as environment or access to the display, depending what `ApplicationName` does, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

As @steeldriver stated, the format was incorrect... I removed the user and everything worked fine. Thank you for the help.

For anyone with a similar problem this is the correct syntax:

```
* * * * * cd "/ApplicationPath" && ./ApplicationName
```

Without the user.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the full path of the application and the name all at once.  Like this:

`* * * * * /ApplicationPath/ApplicationName`